# Deploying Experience site fails due to 'The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again.'

Tags: error, digital-experience, experience-bundle

I am trying to deploy my Experience site to production with a change set, however I keep hitting
`The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again.`
Even though I am not using Experience Bundles to deploy. I have not been able to find any explanation. Does anybody know what I can do about this error?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve yours ?

Comment: I actually have by removing all images/static resources from the change set. Hope that helps you as well!

Comment: Thanks for the cue, Eszter. That is interesting because, at the same time, I have an unexplained error with a StaticResource !!  BTW, I'm using CumulusCI which in turn uses SFDX.